# I don't have access to the azure customvision.ai portal and azure speech studio

Tags: azure, speech, microsoft-custom-vision

When I access the respective URL of each portal.
I enter my credentials and it gives me this error:
-CustomVision AI:
Pick an account
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Directorio predeterminado' and cannot access the application '6c880f2a-97be-46e2-b5aa-36a846ff8020' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

-Speech Studio:
Pick an account
to continue to Speech Studio
Get state-of-the-art speech to text, lifelike text to speech, and award-winning speaker recognition.
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Directorio predeterminado' and cannot access the application '4e09c6ac-4372-45b7-a977-e9f89e673e32' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

Answer (score 0):

The account you are using must be a ***personal Microsoft account*** (e.g `username@outlook.com` )

You have to use your ***tenant user*** account like `username@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`

Still if you are looking to use the same account to access then please refer this [***MS DOC***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20new%20guest%20user%20in%20Azure%20AD,automatically%20added%20to%20the%20directory%20as%20a%20guest.)  to add a **guest user** in a tenant .

**NOTE:-**

If the user is already added as a guest user then you have to use user name as `username_outlook.com#EXT#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com` .

Answer (score 0):

I have already used custom vision and speech with this same user (account) And then this access problem started. Now add a new user to keep testing and return:

Request Id: 965953bc-e0d6-4c84-a880-c9ed4b6e6503
Correlation Id: f9a72d18-4f78-4d35-a419-42b5350e626b
Timestamp: 2022-01-13T13:43:11Z
Message: AADSTS50020: User account 'ppiova@ppiovahotmail.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/62cd79b3-b9c3-49ea-a187-4a87791bb175/' does not exist in tenant 'Directorio predeterminado' and cannot access the application '4e09c6ac-4372-45b7-a977-e9f89e673e32'(Custom Speech AI Portal) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.